# Java: Calling InputStream.read with long offset and length parameters

Tags: java, inputstream, long-integer

When calling the `read` method on an InputStream object, with the `off` and `len` arguments being `long`s, it apparently can't do it:

```
The method read(byte[], int, int) in the type InputStream is not applicable for the arguments (byte[], long, long)
```

Do I **really** have to read it in blocks then? Is there some easy fix? Why can't they just have an overload?

Comment: _Why can't they just have an overload?_ What answer are you expecting here? That's the way the API was designed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Optimally I was hoping for "Just use the other read method in the InputStreamHelpers class" but I'm pretty sure that's a bit of a `long` shot.

Comment: `if(offset > Integer.MAX_VALUE || length > Integer.MAX_VALUE || offset < 0 || length < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(); return read(array, (int)offset, (int)length);` - there's your helper function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4)

> **Arrays must be indexed by `int` values;** `short`, `byte`, or `char` values may
>   also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary
>   numeric promotion (§5.6.1) and become int values.

Providing a `byte[]` and a `long` `len` would simply not make sense. No such API exists.

Comment: And what about the offset?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi What about it? The offset will also be used to create the "read" index into the `byte[]`. It can't be a `long` either, that would potentially put it outside the range.

Comment: Yes now I see! The API is terrible, I thought of it right after posting the comment! And I think, it's confusing! I thought that the offset was with respect to the stream and not the array, I can see why one would want what the API does anyway. I solved the problem, and in fact your answer was very helpful. I am really not a Java programmer, but I HAVE to write Java code because now I am doing APPs.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi There's a [`skip(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip-long-) method for something like that.